# Apple MDM settings won't go through because WiFi is always offline

Tags: ios, ipad, wifi, software-update, mobile-device-management

I can manage settings, apps and updates from Apple's MDM but changes won't get applied because WiFi is always off if I don't manually start using the iPads.

iPads are in charging cart whole night and all updates are in pending state. In the morning people start using iPads and WiFi goes automatically on. Updates and changes start rolling. Users have to wait.

How to configure iPads to turn WiFi periodically on so updates can happen at night time?